# Wordpress - /attributes/attribute to /attribute in URL

Tags: wordpress, url, woocommerce, attributes

My client wants to change default woocommerce URL for product attributes from /attributes/attribute to /attribute on product listing by attribute pages, is there any way to do that? Thank you in advance

so now url goes: **www.mywebsite.com/colors/red**

url that we need: **www.mywebsite.com/red**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achieve this by changing the Permalinks base in Settings -> Permalinks.

Go to Permalinks settings and change the **" Product attribute base "** to **"/attribute/"**

Refer to the below screenshot for reference.

[image]

Comment: Thank You for Your time, that could work but I found solution in 'WP htaccess control' plugin which allows me to strip any of these from URLs

Comment: Glad that you found a solution. This one is a better one compared to using a plugin. Do accept this answer so that someone else might find it helpful. Thanks